# Platform Grills Scroll Animation - 2D Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add platform scroll animation just for visual effect purpose. Because I have started moving platform objects using Physics.

But now I want to add some animation for the ground platform grills so that moving objects will look more natural.

Here is the platform for that I want to add scroll effect or animation:
[image]

I want to scroll the grills those exist on the platform either on the left or right side.

Please give me some idea :)

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try to use Unity animations?

Comment: Normal Sprite I can't able to scroll because it gets visible on the other side. I want something that remains within the platform limitation though it's scrolling. Otherwise stripe sprite become visible after platform limit is over or at the edge.

Comment: Just make the elements child of the platform. Also no point in using physics for this type of animation.

Comment: I have not used Physics for this type of animation, I have used Physics to move objects above on it.